# How to lose less as possible bytes in case of a checksum error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary file which I try to decode.

The format is something like this:

```
Fix header bytes - Define the beginning of a package
Type - which type of information it contains
Length - Number of bytes are in the package (with out crc,...)
Message...
CRC8 - checksum
End of Package byte
```

In my program i read byte after byte and then search for the header and read the rest of the message based on the length value. Assuming the CRC8 is not correct, then i can't trust the length value and I would not like to lose all the bytes i read, but just one.

I guess this is a common problem for parsing data...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? Do you have an example of the code, and where the problem is?

Comment: If the checksum is incorrect you lose a whole package, with crc8 you cannot fix the rest. How do you imagine losing only one byte?

Comment: @TamasHegedus, I read byte after byte and search for my 'fix header bytes'm then assuming the length i decoded is 1000 bytes and I get a crc8 error. In this case I would like to remove the first byte from the payload and try to search for a new 'fix header bytes'. The problem for me is how to work with the existing payload and in addition the file i read the byte by byte...